# Numpy: filtering parallel arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two parallel *numpy* arrays and I would like to keep only those elements in which *a-value* is larger than 3:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([0.1, 0.15, -0.3, 23.4, 112.5])

c = np.array(list(zip(a, b)))

c = c[c[:, 0] > 3].T

a = c[0]
b = c[1]
```

How do I do it numpy-way?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use boolean indexing:

```
a[a > 3]
# array([ 4.,  5.])

b[a > 3]
# array([  23.4,  112.5])
```

---

```
a, b = a[a > 3], b[a > 3]
```

Comment: Note that the first line, if actually executed, would change the output of the second line (and potentially throw an exception due to length mismatch?)

Comment: it won't if I don't assign the result back to `a`, boolean indexing doesn't modify the array in place.

Comment: as results [  23.4,  112.5] are the only two in b with value greater than 3, b = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) serves as a better example for clarity